# C++ Copy pointer class

Tags: c++

I have a problem. I'm kinda new to C++, so please keep that in mind ^^ So I have function called `::Save( Player* pPlayer )` in which I'm inserting into map `m_mapSAVEDPLAYERS` copy of the player. But firstly I need to create copy of that player, but how? Should I make `Player* pNewPlayer = new Player();` and then... `pNewPlayer = pPlayer` or `*pNewPlayer = *pPlayer`? It has to be on new address so it won't get modified later. Thanks for help.

Comment: Given that you're new to C++, are you *absolutely sure* you need to store pointers to dynamically allocated objects? I would also suggest checking your code for memory leaks.

Comment: Don't use Hungarian Notation, i.e. don't encode type information in names. Use simple names like `player` and `savedPlayers`. And as a general guideline, don't use `new` if you don't know exactly why. Chances are that `std::map<..., Player>` and passing arguments as `Player const&` is all you need. If not, `std::map<..., std::unique_ptr<Player>>` may do the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call a copy c'tor.

```
Player* pNewPlayer = new Player(*pPlayer);
```

And be sure not to dereference a null valued pointer.